# Adding another option when the select dropdown is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a new select option in my HTML when they click it

```
<select class="statusButtonChange statusButton " data-value="49506">
    <option value="0" selected=""></option>
    <option value="1">Close</option>
    <option value="2" disabled="" style="color:grey;">Taken</option>
</select>
```

This new option is dynamic and will be coming from an API response...  I'm parsing the var value from the API response but for now, I made it static just to test.

Right now, I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var k = 1
    $(".statusButton").on('focus', function () {
        var value = "Disable";
        var new_v = "";
        var html = $(".statusButton").html();

        if (k == 1) {
            if (value == "Disable") {
                new_v = "<option value='Disable' >Disable</option>";
            }
            else if (value == "Enable") {
                new_v = "<option value='Enable' >Enable</option>"
            }
            var full = html + "" + new_v;
            $(".statusButton").html(full);
            k = 2;
        }
    });
});
```

It is working on JSFiddle but when I try to integrate it on my website, it's not reading it, even just the console log. WHat am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to change `.html` to `.append`

Comment: you should be posting your implemented code in your application, as this is complete working code, so there might be issue while you are adding new dynamic option from you api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong, but I think a better approach might be to use jQuery's append method (https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Consider:

```
...
$(".statusButton").on('focus', function () {
    var value = "Disable";
    var new_v = "";
    var $statusButton = $(".statusButton");
    if(k == 1){
        if(value == "Disable")
        {
            $statusButton.append("<option value='Disable' >Disable</option>");
        }
        else if(value == "Enable")
       {
           $statusButton.append("<option value='Enable' >Enable</option>")
       }
...
```

If you do things that way, you don't have to mess around with any extra `.html` calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is short answer without creating too many variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var k = 1
  $(".statusButton").on('focus', function() {
    var value = "Disable";
    if (k == 1) {
      if (value == "Disable") {
        $(".statusButton").append("<option value='Disable' >Disable</option>");
      } else if (value == "Enable") {
        $(".statusButton").append("<option value='Enable' >Enable</option>")
      }
      k = 2;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="statusButtonChange statusButton " data-value="49506">
  <option value="0" selected=""></option>
  <option value="1">Close</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="" style="color:grey;">Taken</option>
</select>
```